# How to repeat Jenkins job if it fails

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have Java Cucumber tests running on Jenkins. I would like to achieve something like repeat the job in it fails or even better repeat the Cucumber feature if it fails? I dont see any option to run test multiple times. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [retry step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/running-multiple-steps/#timeouts-retries-and-more)

```
retry(3) {
   sh './flaky-command.sh'
}
```

Comment: Thanks i wiil try it.